# Receiving a responseText using xmlHttpRequest that i'm unsure about

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, pdo

I am using this code to add data to a database using ajax. Here is the html:

```
<form>
          Product Name:</br>
          <input type=text name=productName id="addProductName"></br>
          Product Description:</br>
          <input type=text name=productDescription id="addProductDescription"></br>
          Product Quantity:</br>
          <input type=number name=productQuantity id="addProductQuantity"></br>
          <button id="addProduct" type=button>Add Product</button>
        </form>
        <div id="productAdded">test</div>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/test.js"></script>
```

Here is the javascript file test.js:

```
var xmlhttp;
function getXmlHttpRequest(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
      {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
}

function addProduct(){
  getXmlHttpRequest();
  var productName = document.getElementById("addProductName");
  var productDescription = document.getElementById("addProductDescription");
  var productQuantity = document.getElementById("addProductQuantity");
  var url = "insert.php?a=" + productName + "&b=" + productDescription + "&c=" + productQuantity;
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("productAdded").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
      }
    };
}

var button;
button = document.getElementById("addProduct");
button.addEventListener("click", addProduct);
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "products";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $productName = $_GET['a'];
  $productDescription = $_GET['b'];
  $productQuantity = $_GET['c'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductQuantity) VALUES ('$productName','$productDescription','$productQuantity')";
  $conn->exec($sql);
  echo 'Product ' . $productName . ' with quantity: ' . $productQuantity . ' Added';
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

I am getting all of the results that i expect except when i look at my database table i am seeing this instead of the data that was entered into the form:

[object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `getElementById` an `HTMLInputElement` is returned. After that you need to get the value of this element:

```
var productName = document.getElementById("addProductName").value;
var productDescription = document.getElementById("addProductDescription").value;
var productQuantity = document.getElementById("addProductQuantity").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually getting the values from the input fields, use the value property to get it.

```
var productName = document.getElementById("addProductName").value;
var productDescription = document.getElementById("addProductDescription").value;
var productQuantity = document.getElementById("addProductQuantity").value;
```

also you should encode the date incase there ar any special characters in then

```
var url = "insert.php?a=" + encodeURIComponent(productName) + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(productDescription) + "&c=" + encodeURIComponent(productQuantity);
```